# Консольное приложение, которое считывает число и выводит ASCII-арт

Tags: java, алгоритм

Помогите пожалуйста, разработать консольное приложение, которое считывает число и выводит так как показано на данном рисунке

```
Enter number 123456789
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не прошу написать программу за меня( хотя не откажусь).

Comment: Уточните вопрос, что именно вызывает сложности?

Comment: ну я так понимаю задается условие( верно?)  А вот через какую команду вывести сообщение пользователю?

Comment: System.out.println("тут число "); Я правильно понял?

Comment: @DevilScream, если вы не просите написать программу за вас, тогда конкретизируйте вопрос. А иначе "**сделайте за меня**" в чистом виде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу описать вам вариант алгоритма реализации.

1. Для каждой цифры нужно заранее сохранить ее отображение в виде массива из 7 строк по 7 символов. Еще добавьте отображение пробела — массив из семи `" "`. Храните все это в Map.

   ```
   Map<Character, String[]> symbols;
   symbols.put(" ", {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "});
   ```
2. Для формирования строки создавайте массив из 7 `StringBuilder`, инициализируйте его.
3. Число преобразуйте в строку, а ту — в массив `char`'ов.
4. Проходя циклом по массиву билдеров добавляйте (`.append()`) к каждому соответствующие элементы из отображения, перемежая их пробелами. То есть в  билдер номер N пойдут строки под номером N из каждого массива, соответствующего цифре.
5. Проходя циклом по массиву билдеров создавайте от каждого `.toString()` и выводите на печать.

Comment: @DevilScream: пожалуйста. Если возникнут конкретные затруднения с реализацией — публикуйте новый вопрос. Только не предлагайте за вас всё сделать, это не одобряется )

Comment: Я по национальности узбек,а еще занимаюсь испанским,английским и языками програм. Маленько затрудняюсь вопрос на русском формулировать. Спасибо за ваш ответ.

Comment: @DevilScream: ого, да вы полиглот. Кстати, никаких проблем с языком я не вижу, вы грамотно пишете. Минусы на вопросе не за формулировку, а за "написать программу за меня". У нас тут есть постоянная проблема с тем, что приходят студенты и просят за них сделать лабораторные, а сами ничему не учатся. Потому и реакция такая.

Comment: В исходном варианте я писал что не нужно делать за меня(хотя не откажусь)

Comment: @DevilScream: даже так не стоит писать, не провоцируйте )))